# Smoothness of the parallel surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

For the "class $C^n$", I use the following *definition* from Rainer Kress's *Linear Integral Equations*(2nd edition):

> A bounded open domain $D\subset{\mathbb R}^m$ with boundary $\partial D$ is said to be of class $C^n$, $n\in{\mathbb N}$, if the closure $\bar D$ admits a finite open covering
>   $$
> \bar{D}\subset\bigcup^p_{q=1}V_q
> $$
>   such that for each of those $V_q$ that intersect with the boundary $\partial D$ we have the properties: The intersection $V_q\cap \bar D$ can be mapped bijectively onto the half-ball $$H:=\{x\in{\mathbb R}^m:|x|<1,x_m\geq 0 \}$$ in ${\mathbb R}^m$, this mapping and its inverse are $n$ times continuously differentiable, and the intersection $V_q\cap\partial D$ is mapped onto the disk $H\cap\{x\in{\mathbb R}^m;x_m=0\}$. We express the property of a domain $D$ to be of class $C^n$ also by saying that its boundary $\partial D$ is of class $C^n$.

Here is my **question**:

Let $D$ be an open bounded domain in ${\mathbb R}^m(m=2,3)$. Defined the **parallel surfaces**
$$
\partial D_h:=\{z=x+h\nu(x):x\in\partial D\}
$$
with a real parameter $h$ [**EDIT**: where $\nu(x)$ is the unit normal vector of $\partial D$ directed into the exterior domain ${\mathbb R}^m\setminus \bar D$]. If $\partial D$ is assumed to be of class $C^2$, how can I see that $\partial D_h$ is of class $C^1$?

---

#### MOTIVATION/BACKGROUND

This question might be rather elementary in differential geometry (DG). But I cannot figure out the answer since I am a beginner in DG. I get this problem when I am learning the potential theory in PDE. I don't have any intuition that why the parallel surface is *less* smoother than the original boundary from the definition. I wrongly thought that it should be smoother.

Comment: What's $\nu$ here? Is it a normal vector, or something?

Comment: The normal vector is determined by the first partials of the surface parametrization, so intuitively the first partials of the parametrization for $\partial D_h$ should be involve the second partials of the original surface parametrization. I don't understand how to convert that concept into a meaningful proof given that textbook's definition of $C^n$ though.

Comment: Presumably you need $|h|$ sufficiently small? Else it is easy to construct counterexamples where the regularity for $\partial D_h$ is even worse.

Comment: @Willie: +1. Hmm, I think so. (I am also interested in how to actually give the counterexample.) :-) I guess the "parallel surface" here is also called [tubular neighborhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood). I still don't know how to write down the proof yet. Maybe I need to "formalize" anon's comment?